# Defining symbolic string constants which have the same name and value

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a situation where I've got a number of strings that I want to be able to use symbolically, ie as if I'd declared a macro

```
#define kBlahProperty "kBlahProperty"
#define kFooProperty "kFooProperty"
```

There are various reasons why I can't use an enum (for more context see this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342241/creating-debugger-friendly-enums-for-property-table)), such as getting useful info in the debugger, serialising data in a readable format and dealing with sets of properties defined in different source files.

Typical usage:

```
setProperty(kBlahProperty, 6);
if (otherProperty==kBlahProperty) { doStuff(); }
std::cout << "property type: " << kBlahProperty;  // outputs "kBlahProperty" rather than an enum
```

There may be many of these properties, and to ease definition I'd like to be able to declare them like this, in one place only:

```
DEFINE_PROPERTY(kBlahProperty)
DEFINE_PROPERTY(kFooProperty)
```

However, I can't find a way of defining a macro that will itself expand to #define (I've tried a couple of examples with the '#' and '##' operators, but getting to paste the '#define' is the problem).

An alternative tack was to define the macro to expand as a `char*`:

```
#define DEFINE_PROPERTY(propName) const char8* propName=#propName
```

but this has the problem that it gets defined in each compilation unit and hence linker errors. If I change it to use `extern` then I can't define it to use the string itself -- that has to go in the .cpp file and so now I would need to declare all these properties in the header and define them again in the cpp file, so you have a list in two places.

So is there a good way of defining these strings so that you can just declare them once?  I have access to boost preprocessor, but only to a small subset of C++-0x (so [in-class constant initialisers](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init) are out).

Comment: Since you're using C++, why not use `std::string` for strings? Things like the comparison can't be done if you by mistake switch the order of the operands in the comparison if you use pointers (or arrays).

Comment: Just FWIW, a macro that expanded to a macro wouldn't do you any good anyway: "The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one..."

Comment: Simple (if ugly) way  -- define the macro to include extern only if another symbol is not defined, and define that symbol in exactly one compilation unit before you include the header

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: two reasons for not using `std::string` - (1) it still requires a separate declaration and definition, just as `char*` does, and (2) it would have to be a static constant and that would run the risk of order of static order of initialisation problems (ie no guarantee it would be constructed before anything else that may refer to it)

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I suspected that may be the case

Comment: @antlersoft - I'm not sure I understand - can you give an example? Do you mean that everything is declared in a single file and is referenced once in a header and once in a cpp file, and the macro expansion is different in each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple (if ugly) way -- define the macro to include extern only if another symbol is not defined, and define that symbol in exactly one compilation unit before you include the header

With example (include guards omitted for clarity)

```
#ifdef IN_CPP
#define DEFINE_PROPERTY(propName) const char8* propName=#propName;
#else
#define DEFINE_PROPERTY(propName) extern const char8* propName;
#endif
```

In exactly one compilation unit:

```
#define IN_CPP 1
#include "header.h"
```

In remaining compilation units:

```
#include "header.h"
```

Comment: I'd suggest a variation to this: Make the declared objects constant. ATM it's just a non-const pointer to a constant char8. Making it const makes the linkage internal, like static. With a decent compiler and string pooling, you don't even waste any memory.

Comment: Is there a reason the initializer is also on the `extern` ? Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your macro to have and #ifdef so it has two paths - if and else.  Then in the header it just *declares* your propName.  Then in your .cpp file, define a preprocessor variable before you include your header.  That define will make your macro *define* the propName.

Comment: is this the same suggestion as @antlersoft above?

Comment: Also, if there's going to be alot of these properties, consider using const char[] instead of const char *.  The latter uses additional space to store the pointer, the former does not.

Comment: I typed this up with actual code to answer the question, but this is likely sufficient so I won't bother. This is not uncommon. Microsoft does this with their INITGUID mechanism for declaring vs. defining common application GUIDs.